# Trying to call a function outside of an if statement

Tags: python

I'm doing some Python exercises and I came across a frustrating error:

```
line 18, in <module>
    modulo()

NameError: name 'modulo' is not defined
```

Code is below:

```
number = input("Please enter a number: ")

if number.isdigit():
    def modulo():
        answer = int(number) % 2

        if answer == 0:
            print("Your number, " + number + " is even.")
        elif answer > 0:
            print("Your number, " + number + " is odd.")
        else:
            print("Error. Please try again.")

else:
    print("Please try again")

modulo()
```

Comment: The function is defined inside the if-statement, but used outside. That won't work if the if-statement never runs.

Comment: @rdas Thank you! jeez that was stupid. fixed it by calling it inside the if statement. I appreciate the fast response.

Comment: Just a general advice, python has scopes and things defined inside the scope is not accessible outside it. This means that e.g. variables used in functions are not accessible to anything outside the function and for definitions they have to be run before they can be called.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Make `modulo` accept an argument, define it outside the if-statement

```
def modulo(num):
  answer = int(num) % 2
  if answer == 0:
    print("Your number, " + num + " is even.")
  elif answer > 0:
    print("Your number, " + num + " is odd.")
  else:
    print("Error. Please try again.")

number = input("Please enter a number: ")

if number.isdigit():
    modulo(number)
else:
    print("Please try again")
```

Comment: Thank you! new to python this helped out a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your function outside the if statement, in this case the function will be defined ONLY if `number.isdigit()` is `True`.